# Periodical tasks for each entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I often have models that are a local copy of some remote resource, which needs to be periodically kept in sync.

```
Task(
    url="/keep_in_sync", 
    params={'entity_id':entity_id}, 
    name="sync-%s" % entity_id,
    countdown=3600
).add()
```

Inside keep_in_sync any changes are saved to the model and a new task is scheduled to happen again later.

Now, while superficially this seems like a nice solution, in practice you might become worried if all the necessary tasks have really been added or not. Maybe you have entities representing the level of food pellets inside your hamster cages so that an automated email can be sent to your housekeeper to feed them. But then a few weeks later when you come back from your holiday, you find several of your hamsters starving.

It then starts seeming like a good idea to make a script that goes through each entity and makes sure that the proper task really is in the queue for it. But neither Task nor Queue classes have any method for checking if a task exists or not.

Can you save the hamsters and come up with a nicer way to make sure that a method really for sure is being periodically called for each entity?

**Update**

It seems that if you want to be really sure that tasks are scheduled, you need to keep track of your own tasks as Nick Johnson suggests. Not ready to let go of the convenient task queue, so for the time being will just tolerate the uncertainty of being unable to check if tasks are really scheduled or not.

Comment: +1 for the hamster metaphor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of enqueueing a task per entity, handle multiple entities in a single task. This can be triggered by a daily cron job, for instance, which fans out to multiple tasks. As well as ensuring you execute your code for each entity, you can also take advantage of asynchronous URLFetch to synchronize with the external resource more efficiently, and batch puts and gets from the datastore to make the updates more efficient.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea, especially as it might save some resources. With enough entities, there might not be enough time to start all the tasks in a single cron job handler though, so not sure how that fanning out would exactly work.

Comment: You can split it into few steps, block by block, by using cursor

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an exception (TaskAlreadyExistsError) if there already such task in queue (same url and same params). So, don't worry, just all of them into queue, and remember to catch exceptions.

You can find full list of exceptions here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/exceptions.html